# Text Base64 to Hex Base64

Tags: c++, encoding, base64

I'm having an issue where one api I use converts base64 by Hex and another one converts by Text. I need to be able to convert the hex string to text so that the encoding is the same for both api's.
https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base64_encode.html
This page contains a good example, if I input

```
fb95 <- HEX -- BASE64-> +5U=
fb95 <- TEXT -- BASE64-> ZmI5NQ==
```

Is there a way to convert a

```
std::string text("fb95");
```

to it's hex representation that is encoded as +5U=

or convert

```
std::string b64("ZmI5NQ==");
```

to +5U=

Comment: Looks like you aren't encoding a hex string but the integer 0xfb95.

Comment: It looks like you have to convert the hex-codes into characters first. That's rather simple: You have to convert pairs of hex digits where every first hex-digit feeds the upper four bits of the `char` and the next the lower four bits. Btw. `std::istream` provides a `std::hex` which can be used for formatted input of values. [std::stoi()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) has an extra argument `base` for that purpose. However, with either of them you shouldn't forget to "break" the string into pairs of hex-digits by yourself as these functions are intended for `int`.

Comment: The string "fb95" is a **base16** conversion of the data.  It appears you want a **base16 to base64** conversion, rather than a **text to base64** conversion.  You just need to write a base16 to base64 converter.